# All commands are not working on Mac OS X Lion

Tags: terminal, osx-lion

I am faced with a problem, that I can't run even a single command on my Mac OS X Lion terminal, even "ls" command, when i print $PATH variable, found

```
My-Mac:/ Mac$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/git/bin
```

Please help me if you have guys have any solution for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with `export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin` to get your commands back.

If you open up a new terminal, does it start with `PATH` as `/usr/local/git/bin`? If so, it sounds like your git installation screwed up your paths in `/etc/paths`, or your `/etc/profile`

Mine has (`/etc/paths`):

```
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/bin
```

And `/etc/profile` should contain the following somewhere:

```
if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
    eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
fi
```

Do these files contain similar lines on your system? If not, we'll  need to see what they do contain and then properly merge them with what should be in there. If they check out, we'll look into your `/etc/bashrc` or local profile configurations.

Comment: got the solution, :)
there is a .bash_profile file in my home dir, which executed when i open up the terminal , i deleted that file, its containing that git path only

Comment: Awesome! Your git applications might not work now, so you might consider adding `/usr/local/git/bin` to the bottom of `/etc/paths` on it's own line if you haven't already.