# Fix Mac OS X bash

Tags: bash, terminal, osx-mountain-lion

When I start my Terminal I get this error. I have no clue how to fix that and where it comes from.

```
Last login: Fri Nov 30 21:46:06 on ttys000
-bash: export: `/usr/local/bin': not a valid identifier
```

Answer (score 2):

Most likely one of the 'export' command in your .bashrc or .bash_profile is mis-configured.

Open up your favorite text editor and view the file(s) in your home directory called .bashrc and .bash_profile.

Look for any lines that begin with

```
export
```

one of the lines should be

```
export PATH='/usr/local/bin'
```

there might be spaces between PATH and the first '

```
export PATH = '/usr/local/bin'  #<----WRONG remove spaces
```

if not, copy the contents here and let's have a look.

An alternative if you can't find it is to grep through your home dir or /etc:

```
grep -l -E '/usr/local/bin' .*
```

make sure you use single quotes to escape the forward slash.
then look at the files it lists for the mis-typed export.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I already checked both files and they were empty (not existed). If I create a ~./bash_profile file with "export PATH='/usr/local/bin'" as content, the error is still there. weird :/

Comment: @nohayeye Those tend to require a reboot, or at least a logout/in to take effect.  Did you try that?

Comment: It also might be `export $PATH` somewhere - the dollar sign does not belong there.

Comment: how about ~/.bash_login, ~/.profile. also how about /etc/profile.

Comment: just modified the answer to use grep to find the file.

Comment: You cannot just export the whole path to just usr/local/bin – append the existing path as well: `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`

Answer (score 1):

OSX has used the path locations in a few files over the 10.6/7/8:

```
~/.profile     #local user
/etc/profile   #system wide defaults for ^
/etc/paths     #<---This is probably the one you want to check in.
```

Check all of those for the path's, as @choroba said above the $ is only for the end of the line, so similar to: `export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/usr/sbin:$PATH`

Comment: That's how they look like: http://cl.ly/LGdu No $PATH


//EDIT: Sorry wrong screenshot.

Comment: @nohayeye Odd.  Do command line tools work (outside of vi/m as it appears above)?  I like where John was going, but I would take it further.  Something like `for i in \`find / -maxdepth 3 -iname "*profile*"\`; do grep -i "*path*" ${i}; done`  I know that is how it works on linux, so it should work.  Though, it may be a long search...

Comment: I found another topic where someone posted his /etc/paths and /etc/profile. (http://superuser.com/questions/374204/all-commands-are-not-working-on-mac-os-x-lion) I edited my /etc/paths but the "-bash: export: `/usr/local/bin': not a valid identifier" is still there. All command line tools are working. Weeeeird!

Comment: Did you reboot after update?

Comment: I found it! There was a strange $PATH line in "/etc/bashrc". I deleted it, now everything is working fine. Thanks you all for your help! :)